# What is the proper way to handle conan profiles in a container?

Tags: docker, conan

I want to pack a service in a container. The service is built with usage of conan. How would you put conan profiles (separate repo from the service) in ~/.conan/profiles? I suppose git clone inside a container is not the best solution (private ssh keys etc). Copying conan profile from host to a container is not the best either (conan profile would have to be inside the service folder and then moved to container's ~/.conan/profiles)

Is pinning conan profile repo as a submodule to the service the only option?

```
service
   - conan-profiles
   - rest of the service files
```

And in the Dockerfile

```
COPY conan-profiles/ /root/.conan/profiles/
COPY . /service
```

Comment: [conan config install](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/config.html) for sure. You can redistribute your profiles everywhere, so if need to update something, don't need to rebuild your docker image exactly, if you install your profiles for every new build. But the real advantage is the redistribution, as you don't need to keep your profiles files in your repo, then copy to docker image, instead, you can store of profiles in a git repo, them install in your machine, or in a docker image.

Comment: @uilianries thanks, that looks promising. would it work for conan profiles that are hidden behind a VPN?

Comment: Yes, VPN is not a blocker. I myself, use VPN + conan config command.

Comment: Have you tried with `RUN conan config install <url>`  ?